# Python3.6 version does not print correct data

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-3.6, centos7

I have installed Centos7 and added python3.6 from epel-repository.subversion python-3.6.3
I am trying to check python 3.6 version via small script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python36
  import sys

   print(sys.version)
```

The moment I run it in a IDE I am getting this :

> 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10) 
>   [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

Why isn't it showing the python3 version?

Comment: probably because you are running python 2.7

Comment: It seems like you have `python2.7` and `python3.6` both installed in your pc write `python` then see what version it gives you if its python 2.7 then `exit()`  and write `python3.6` in terminal then see the version! The reason your script is giving you 2.7 is that your default version in IDE is python 2.7

Comment: I regret that we can't those cerbers who minus newcomers. We already have another process for filtering bad questions. And this question is not bad for nube. I'm plusing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure Geany to use python3.

From the Geany menu bar > Build > Set build command > Execute command

use the following command:

```
python3 "%f"
```

instead of:

```
python "%f"
```

On Atom , install `script`:

```
apm install script
```

Your script should print the `python 3.x` version.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

Answer (score 0):

```

## !/usr/bin/python36

```

First line. Remove `env`

A little advice: learn  [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)

Comment: IDE does not matter. What do you see if you run `python3 [your_script].py`, `python2 [your_script].py` and `python [your_script].py` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate what ide you are using

Anyway, since you don't need to compile python, it is really easy to start your script from command line:

```
cd /script/folder
python3 myscript.py
```

if there is multiple python 3 installed, or a specific one, you can try this command:

```
python36 myscript.py
```

Sometimes you can use a virtualenv (actually it is strongly recommended)
so you first need to create one:

```
python36 -m venv "name/and/path"
```

then you can call this virtual environment by tiping:

```
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

This previous command line can be used in a shell script if you need to automate things

your console should now indicate the name of your virtual environment:

```
(myvirtualenv) [user@host]$
```

from here you can install packages only on this environment

Explained in pictures:
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: I am using **geany**. also checked on **atom**, same python2.7 output.

Comment: yes, this is because your ide is choosing the default python on your os (python2.7)

I use visual studio code, there, you can specify in the settings a virtual environment path (or a global python path) in order to have autocompletion....

On Geany and atom, you can use the integrated console to do launch your scripts. If you check the settings, I'm sure you can find (at least with atom) a way to specify your python env and enjoy autocompletion